# Installing mssql-cli on alpine docker image

Tags: python, docker, alpine-linux

Apparently `mssql-cli` https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/tools/mssql-cli?view=sql-server-ver16 version 1.0.0 can't be installed on Alpine:

- as there is no installation guide for Alpine: https://github.com/dbcli/mssql-cli/blob/main/doc/installation/linux.md
- pip install instructions don't exist and not working for alpine: https://github.com/dbcli/mssql-cli/blob/main/doc/installation/pip.md
- issue exist to enable Alpine support for this python package: mssql-cli: https://github.com/dbcli/mssql-cli/issues/417, but no solution found for this thread.

I must use an existing Alpine based Docker image that already exists with zero vulnerabilities and security hardening in place to install `mssql-cli` pip package.

I have attempted manual installation like this:

```
mkdir /mssql-cli-installer
cd /mssql-cli-installer
wget https://github.com/dbcli/mssql-cli/archive/refs/tags/1.0.tar.gz
tar -xzf 1.0.tar.gz
cd mssql-cli-1.0
pip3 install .
apk add bash
```

and then I execute `bash mssql-cli` which apparently seems to work, but then gives an error after SQL password is supplied. Error is:

```
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/usr/lib/python3.9/site-packages/mssqlcli/mssqltoolsservice/bin/MicrosoftSqlToolsServiceLayer' Exception ignored in: <function MssqlCli.__del__ at 0x7fb638cadaf0> Traceback (most recent call last):   File "/usr/lib/python3.9/site-packages/mssqlcli/mssql_cli.py", line 213, in
__del__
    if self.sqltoolsclient: AttributeError: 'MssqlCli' object has no attribute 'sqltoolsclient'
```

I have also tried this workaround without luck to solve above issue: https://github.com/dbcli/mssql-cli/issues/247#issuecomment-486744989

I understand that Python and Alpine don't go along too well: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/446618/alpine-linux-command-takes-forever#447658, but this is the requirement at hand. Can someone give any hint how should I attempt to solve installing `mssql-cli` on an Alpine Docker container?